Question on harmonic functions in a unit disc D
My question is: Let $u = u(x, y)$ and $v(x, y)$ be two harmonic functions defined in the unit disc $D = \{(x, y) : x^2 + y^2 ≤ 1\}$. If max $u ≥$ max $v$ on the boundary $∂D$, then $u ≥ v$ in $D$. I thought the answer to this would be false, because even if one function is greater than the other in the boundary, they can take any value below the maximum inside the region right?
Could someone confirm this answer, and explain the concept behind the right answer if possible?

You are right. As an example, let $u(x,y)=2x$ and $v(x,y)=-x$; then $\max u = 2 \geq 1=\max v$ on $\partial D$, but $u<v$ in $D$ if $x<0$.

FYI - to get set braces to appear in mathjax, you have to escape them: $\{ x \}$ gives ${x}$.
